# Exp-resso Store: What is the Mollie Webhook?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I'm using store 2.x and (almost!) everything works fine. There is one small thing bugging me. Mollie sends me a warning: the webhook isn't correctly connected.

That's quite obvious; I didn't enter any [webhook](https://www.mollie.com/en/docs/webhook).

My question: What webhook URL should I enter in my account at Mollie?

*Update 20160222 Mollie API webhook image:*

[image]

*Update 20160222 checkout code:*

```
{exp:store:checkout
form_class="form-horizontal"
return="shop/order/ORDER_HASH"
error_handling="inline"
error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}

{if no_items}
    {redirect="shop/checkout"}
{/if}

 <fieldset>
                    <legend>Payment info</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div><b>{billing_name}</b></div>
                        <div>{billing_address1}</div>
                        <div>{billing_address2}</div>
                        <div>{billing_city} {billing_postcode}</div>
                        <div>{billing_state_name}</div>
                        <div>{billing_country_name}</div>
                        <div>{billing_phone}</div>
                        <div>{order_email}</div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Shipping info</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        {if shipping_same_as_billing}
                            Shipping = billing
                        {if:else}
                            <div><b>{shipping_name}</b></div>
                            <div>{shipping_address1}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_address2}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_city} {shipping_postcode}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_state_name}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_country_name}</div>
                            <div>{shipping_phone}</div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </fieldset>


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Payment</legend>

            {if error:payment_method}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="alert alert-error">{error:payment_method}</div>
                </div>
            {/if}




       <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="payment_method">Payment</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
                        <option value="PayPal_Express"> Paypal</option>
                        <option value="Mollie_Ideal"> iDeal (via Mollie)</option>


                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Review</legend>

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:60%">Product</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item_qty} &times; {title}</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{item_subtotal}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/items}
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subtotal</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">{order_subtotal}</th>
                    </tr>
                    {if shipping_method}
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shipping ({shipping_method_name})</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{order_shipping}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/if}
                    {if order_handling_val}
                        <tr>
                            <td>Handling</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{order_handling}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/if}
                    {if order_tax_val}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{tax_name} ({tax_percent}%)</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">{order_tax}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {/if}
                    <tr>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th style="text-align:right">{order_total}</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>


<div class="form-actions">
    <a href="{path='shop/checkout2'}" class="button nonprimair">Back</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="checkout" class="button cta" />
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: I'm using this and haven't had this issue; can you post some example checkout code?

Comment: I just updated my question. The checkout code is working, so I don't expect anything strange. But I posted it, just to be sure. I also added an image from the mollie interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen this myself - I think that it's because the server wasn't reachable through Mollie through the entire transaction. I've seen it three instances in the past week:

- When the site is actually offline and I'm going through the flow in Test mode. It can't handshake so it fails.
- When the server isn't responding; I'm finding that in the Mollie logs, the site becomes unreachable every day at 11am like clockwork; presumable something is restarting. I've got a question in to the server people now to see what is scheduled at that time.
- When the site could not handshake back after the transaction. After that pause at 11am, mails stopped coming in immediately. So in that time, a transaction occurred but there was no notification...for about 4-5 minutes. Mollie's logs showed that too (so I'm looking today at the Escort plugin to move transactional mails to Mandrill or Mailgun)